# SQL - Query help

Tags: sql-server

I have problem to calculate number of dates,

how to get date minus date = int value in sql 2005 
Out Put :

```
(1/1/2009 12:00:00 AM - 5/1/2009 12:00:00 AM) = 4
```

Please let me know

Answer (score 2):

```
select datediff(dd, '2009/01/01', '2009/01/05')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, startDate, EndDate)
```